# Where to get $500 in quarters

Tags: coins

We have a laundromat in my apartment complex.  It seems like every few months I have to run to the bank and do the dance of changing bills for quarters.  Since I'm with a credit union, it doesn't always even work, and when it does, they have a limited number of quarters on hand.  (Like...less than $100, I think.)  I'm tired of having to do this every couple months.  I've mostly run out of quarters again, and what with the quarantine, last time I checked, it was harder to get stuff from the bank.  Surely there's somewhere I can exchange like, $500 for quarters?  I'd even be willing to pay a fee of like, $10 or $20, rather than the usual "free".  Anybody know of a method?  (Which doesn't involve simply hitting up a bunch of banks or grocery stores in the same day?)

Comment: I would treat it as any other large cash transaction and call your local credit union a week or so in advance. This Tooth Fairy has done that with $2 bills previously.

Comment: Why don't you talk to the Laundomat owner, he probably has lots of quarters that he wants to exchange for bills?

Comment: Are you the laundromat owner, trying to stock the change machine at the laundromat, or are you a laundromat patron, and the laundromat doesn't have its own change machine?

Comment: Question: Why do you rob banks? Answer: Because that's were the money is.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco Yeah, it'd probably help to call in advance; thanks.

Comment: @Aganju That's an interesting solution, though; I may try that one; thanks.

Comment: @shoover I'm a patron - there's no change machine.

Comment: From the bank, probably. Just obey their coronavirus restrictions.

Comment: "rather than the usual "free"" - no, it is NOT usually free. Large amounts of small coin are a service, someone has to roll them, count them. NORMALLY you pay.

Comment: Casinos. Destination entertainment centers including brands like Dave and Busters, Chuck E Cheese.

Comment: Interesting, all the laundromats I've been in (admittedly, not many) have switched to reloadable cards. Perhaps it'll be worth going to a farther location instead.

Comment: Alas, the credit union is not doing shared branching until further notice (and my home credit union is in a different state), and the apartment laundromat is subcontracted to somebody else.  (They're switching to a card-based laundromat service at the end of the year.)  I got one or two loads-of-laundry's worth of quarters changing bills at the CVS and Walgreens, but it still feels like there surely ought to be a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to do some math on how many quarters you need for, say, a year of laundry. A roll of quarters is forty quarters or ten dollars, so divide by ten and round to a convenient number. Then go to your local credit union branch and ask if they can get you that many rolls of quarters.

Even 500 dollars is probably small enough that the teller isn't required by law to ask why you want that much money in quarters, but you may want to be ready to explain your math to the teller. You may need to wait a day or two, or they may send you to a bigger branch to pick up those rolls, but that shouldn't be all that many quarters for a bank.

As an aside, if the laundromat really is costing you $500 a year, getting your own washer would be a better investment than its price in quarters.

Comment: If they do ask just say "I have Pac Man Fever"

Comment: "getting your own washer would be a better investment" That thought occurred to me too, but OP's apartment may not have washer/dryer hookups available

Answer (score 2):

Ask a teller at your credit union, or call/message their customer service. They do this all the time, especially for businesses that have lots of small transactions, like coffee shops, etc. Depending on the amount, they may ask you to order in advance, but this is well within the scope of services banks and credit unions offer.